# How to add JLabel inside a polygon?

Tags: java, dictionary, jlabel, isometric

I am trying to do a [isometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection) map for a game on Java, but I can't find a way to do this. I need to add a `JLabel` for each polygon of the isometric map, so I can use `paint()` for each position. How can I add a `JLabel` for each polygon I draw? I can't get it. I already have my algorithm to draw each position of my isometric map, something like this:

```
//L is the width of the map (that will be the framw width)
//N will be the number of COLUMN, like N*N will be the total number of positions.

//The first position (a,b) that will be

 a=L / (2*N+1)
 b=a . tan(30º

for (int y = 0; y < N; y++) {
     if (y % 2 == 0) { // Se y é PAR
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
           Polygon p = new Polygon();
           p.addPoint(x * a * 2 + a, y * b);
           p.addPoint(x * a * 2 + 2 * a, y * b + b);
           p.addPoint(x * a * 2 + a, y * b + 2 * b);
           p.addPoint(x * a * 2, y * b + b);
           g.drawPolygon(p);
        }
   } else { // if Y is odd
    for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
       Polygon p = new Polygon();
       p.addPoint(x * a * 2 + 2 * a, y * b);
       p.addPoint(x * a * 2 + 3 * a, y * b + b);
       p.addPoint(x * a * 2 + 2 * a, y * b + 2 * b);
       p.addPoint(x * a * 2 + a, y * b + b);
       g.drawPolygon(p);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks alot in advance guys

Comment: Does the JLabel have to be inside the polygon? What exactly is your issue with adding it? Also what are you drawing your polygons on?

Comment: Post your SSCCE that shows the painting of the polygons and how the size of the frame affects the polygons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layout and drawing are really quite different. Layout isn't about exact positioning. You may as well just use drawChars on the Graphics object in the position you want, or cast it into a Graphics2D object and use drawString.

Comment: I wanna use Labels on each position of the isomatric map, because on some positions there will be IMAGES representing heros of my game, do u see?
And in some cases that labels will have a hero.. another case will have a building..
And I can manipulate that by using labels on each position and then use the method paint for each label.
Thanks for ur help guys, I hope u understood me :)